# How to load css files in ClojureScript project with shadow-cljs

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I have a `styles.css` file and I need to load it from a `cljs` to pass it as a `props` to a react lib.

The import in node is:

`import styles from './styles.css'`

Is it possible to do this in ClojureScript with `shadow-cljs`?

Answer (score 7):

Importing `styles.css` in `webpack` is handled by the [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) which you can sort of hook up by following the [webpack](https://clojurescript.org/guides/webpack) guide and exporting things to global objects.

ClojureScript itself (or `shadow-cljs`) does not support anything in that regard but you could possibly create something similar using macros.

Comment: No, not currently. I wrote an alternative in [shadow.markup](https://github.com/thheller/shadow/wiki/shadow.markup) which functions similarly to the `styled-components` library but it isn't documented very well. There are other alternatives using the `garden` clojure lib.